# Proper Handling Connection Error: Connection aborted, BadStatusLine(" ' ",)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been querying data on a web server using the `requests` library in Python. I get the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

I would like my program **not** to abort but test the connection and continue from where it left off. How should I do this?

I have the following code in a function called `query_predix_ts` that queries the web server:

```
r_s = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload2), headers=header_store)
```

Here's the function call:

```
for tag in tags_list:
                if tag in tags_with_dim_list:
                    for dim in dims:
                        try:
                            df = query_predix_ts(t1, t2, tag, 0, this_msk, dim)
                        except(ValueError, NameError) as e:
                            print e
                        if df.shape[0] != 0:
                            sensor_type = tag + dim
                            df['sensor_type'] = sensor_type
                            # print df.head()
                            single_df.append(df)
```

How should I wrap this line within the try-exception so when there is connection error, it continues to try, say 5 times before it aborts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would probably wrap the line in your `query_predix_ts` method because that's the most logical place like so:

```
r_s = None
count = 0
while r_s is None and count < 5:
    try:
        r_s = requests.post(...)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        count += 1

if r_s:
    raise MyException('Could not connect to {host}'.format(...))
```

Alternatively, you could utilize the built-in [retry logic](http://www.coglib.com/~icordasc/blog/2014/12/retries-in-requests.html) in requests & urllib3. For example,

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import retry
from requests import adapters
import requests


def query_predix_ts(...):
    session = requests.Session()
    for scheme in ('http://', 'https://'):
         session.mount(scheme, adapters.HTTPAdapter(
             max_retries=retry.Retry(connect=5),
         ))

    r_s = session.post(...)
```